# How can I figure out the cause of this DLOPEN error while debugging Node.js

Tags: node.js, dlopen

When debugging my node app from Visual Studio 2022 im getting this error. I'm very new to programming so im not really sure how to troubleshoot this.

```
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1210
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\C:\Users\QSUser\choco-gui\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\build\Release\nodegui_core.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1210:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
 >  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\QSUser\choco-gui\node_modules\@nodegui\nodegui\dist\lib\utils\addon.js:3:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}

C:\Users\QSUser\choco-gui\src\src.exe (process 17392) exited with code 1.
```

ive tried `npm update`and deleting and rebuilding my node_modules folder with no avail. When i run my program from terminal `npm start` from my project dir it runs fine

Comment: "When debugging my node app from Visual Studio 2022 ..." - wild guess: VS starts your process in some _other_ directory. There is a project setting which allows you to set this directory, and you may not have done that.

Comment: dlopen is a library in C and C++ that is used to load other libraries. Your error say a module/library couldn't be found, It might be because the lib that it is trying to load does not exist on your computer and need to be installed. Do you know what is this "module" ?